# need explanation on sensor_msgs/LaserScan.msg

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, laser-scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am new in ROS, the **message Definition of a LaserScan.msg** is as follows:-

```
std_msgs/Header header
float32 angle_min
float32 angle_max
float32 angle_increment
float32 time_increment
float32 scan_time
float32 range_min
float32 range_max
float32[] ranges
float32[] intensities
```

**i want to know the what information these variable holds and how can i manipulate them to extract the distance from an obstacle.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198843/need-explanation-on-sensor_msgs/laserscan.msg/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Doc: sensor_msgs..LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) has explanation for all the variables.

Looking at the code [Publish_a_LaserScan_Message](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors#Writing_Code_to_Publish_a_LaserScan_Message) will gives good picture of variables.

laser scanner view of  [hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 laser scanner](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/urg_04lx_ug01.html)

[image: image description]

red,green are x,y-axes

---

Values for above scanner

```
    angle_min= -135 * (pi/180); //angle correspond to FIRST beam in scan ( in rad)
    angle_max= 135 * (pi/180); //angle correspond to LAST beam in scan ( in rad)
    angle_increment =0.25 * (pi/180); // Angular resolution i.e angle between 2 beams

   // lets assume sensor gives 50 scans per second. i.e every 20 milli seconds 1 scan with 1081 beams.
   // Each beam is measured in  (20 ms/ 1081 ) ~ = 0.0185 ms

    time_increment  = (1 / 50) / (1081); 
                                                           
    scan_time = ;   // scan is collected at which time
    range_min =0 ; // in meters
    range_max = 20; // scan can measure upto this range
    // ranges is array of 1081 floats for each laser beam
    ranges[0] = //distance measure corresponds to angle -135 deg
    ranges[1] = //distance measure corresponds to angle -134.75 deg
    .
    .
    .
    ranges[1080] = //distance measure corresponds to angle +135 deg


    //To understand Intensities 
    //if a laser beam hits reflective surface like glass it will have intensity 1. 
    //And if beam hit some surface which absorbs laser , then intensity is zero. 
    //Middle values are different surfaces in between.
```

---

```
Header header            # timestamp in the header is the acquisition time of 
                         # the first ray in the scan.
                         #
                         # in frame frame_id, angles are measured around 
                         # the positive Z axis (counterclockwise, if Z is up)
                         # with zero angle being forward along the x axis
                         
float32 angle_min        # start angle of the scan [rad]
float32 angle_max        # end angle of the scan [rad]
float32 angle_increment  # angular distance between measurements [rad]

float32 time_increment   # time between measurements [seconds] - if your scanner
                         # is moving, this will be used in interpolating position
                         # of 3d points
float32 scan_time        # time between scans [seconds]

float32 range_min        # minimum range value [m]
float32 range_max        # maximum range value [m]

float32[] ranges         # range data [m] (Note: values < range_min or > range_max should be discarded)
float32[] intensities    # intensity data [device-specific units].  If your
                         # device does not provide intensities, please leave
                         # the array empty.
```

---

Obstacle distance calculation is easy

[image description http://www.physics.hmc.edu/courses/p057/pmwiki/uploads/Physics/Euler2.png](http://www.physics.hmc.edu/courses/p057/pmwiki/uploads/Physics/Euler2.png)

if r, θ are range and angle from one scan laser scan obstacle is at (x,y) = ( rcosθ, rsinθ )  in laser frame.

To make sense about θ , here imagine your laser has 180 deg view and now looking towards x-axis and ray along postive y-axis is +90 degress and negative y-axis is -90 degree.

```
agnle_min = -90    
agnle_max = 90
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 27

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-04**:
hi @bvbdort, i have gone through [Doc: sensor_msgs..LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html), but i could not properly understand what those variable holds in them eg range_max, ranges, intensities ect, that's why I've posted this question for a brief explanation.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-04**:
@Aarif , Max reading depends on what laser you are using , it can be 5m or 30m or different depending on laser you are using. Min reading is zero. To understand Intensities , if a laser beam hits reflective surface like glass it will have intenstiy 1.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-04**:
And if beam hit some suface which absorbs laser , then intensity is zero. and middle values are different sufaces with relective nature.

Please let me know what exactly you are trying to understand.

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-04**:
thank you so much @bvbdort, can you please explain me about all the variables, thanks in advance. :)

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-04**:
hi @bvbdort, i have a P3AT spawned in Usarsim Simulator, i want measure its distance with wall or any other obstacle, for this i need to subscribe laser_scan topic which will give the data in the laser_scan.msg format which has these variables, thats why i wanted to know about these variables. Thnks

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-04**:
if you are looking for lms200 values specifically, go through [lms200 data sheet](http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/docs/sick-lms-technical-description.pdf)

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-05**:
Thank you very much @bvbdort, now i've understand the things. :)

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2016-02-18**:
Wow. (pi/3.14) Won't they be just 1 and should be eliminated instead.

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2016-03-03**:
Yeah, I don't understand why he puts  (pi/3.14)???

angle_min= -135 * (pi/3.14); //angle correspond to FIRST beam in scan ( in rad)
angle_max= 135 * (pi/3.14); //angle correspond to LAST beam in scan ( in rad)

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2016-03-05**:
Sorry Its a mistake, it  was pi/180 to convert degrees to radians.  Just updated the answer.

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-03-26**:
@bvbdort Is the `θ` mentioned equivalent to `angle_increment` of the lidar?

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-03-26**:
@bvbdort I am still confused about the `θ`, could you please explaining it more specifically?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2019-03-27**:
`θ` is the angle of the ray.  For example, first ray will have angle_min and last ray wil have angle_max.

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-03-27**:
@bvbdort so `θ` equals `angle_min+angle_increment*ray_index`?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2019-04-08**:
............yes.......

**Comment by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on 2020-07-19**:
thank you so much! This is the best and most simplified response on this topic. It helped me a lot!